# Get parent component in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 5.1. I have a panel with a definition of button in the items-section with a listerner for event 'click'. The 'this'-keyword refers here to the button itself. But I want a new component to my panel, so I need reference to this panel in the listener-function. 'this.getParent().add(...)' doesn't function, no function error, this.container.getParent().add(...) results in the same error. What is the correct way?

Comment: You need to post the code.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.up('panel')` in the first argument of the click function, which is the button itself.

Or in ExtJS 5 define a `reference` property in your panel, and use

`this.lookupReference('your_reference_in_panel');`

Comment: Attribute selectors for components are very rarely used, especially in a context where you're looking upward.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli What do you mean with "rarely used"? i've never read anything about it being a bad practice or something.

Comment: You could also use Ext.ComponentQuery: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: Typically, you don't assign a "name" attribute to a panel. It's not idiomatic.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Where do you see a name here? `panel` is xtype, not a name. This is a proper way of referencing a parent and it says so right in the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-up If you have your idiomatic answer please post it so we can downvote it instead, as it's most likely wrong.

Comment: @serg Originally my post was with `.up('panel[name="whatever"]')`. I edited it after the correction of Evan

Comment: I have used `.up('panel[title=ABC]')` at least once, because I had a field inside a panel inside a tabpanel inside a panel with title ABC, and wanted to get the top panel.

Comment: @Alexander yes, and that's why i post my solution with that selector, because i was in situations similar to yours. The problem here (i think) is that `name` is not a correct attribute for a panel, instead it's better to use reference, itemId or title.